# meteor.js - is it possible to run direct database queries on a deployed project?

Tags: meteor

Pretty much the title... I deployed a meteor project but I need to tweak some values in the database. Is this possible without writing some code and just doing direct mongo queries? Or barring that, can I wipe the data on the deployed project's database and have a fresh start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To gain direct mongo access to the database of your deployed app, open up your terminal and type in: `meteor mongo yourproject.meteor.com`

If you're trying to reset your databases in production, assuming you still have the files you deployed with, simply run `meteor deploy yourproject.meteor.com --delete` and, after it deletes, run `meteor deploy yourproject.meteor.com`. This is all assuming you have the files you deployed with and you're in that subdirectory currently.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I didn't see this in the docs but now that I read the usage on "meteor deploy" I see it. I should have RTFM D: Do you know if there is a better resource besides stackoverflow to ask simple questions? Like I'm curious about security stuff, when you do Meteor.call is there a way to know which client called that, to prevent them from changing other client's data? I should probably start a new question...

Comment: Rule of thumb, you probably shouldn't have `Meteor.call` methods any user can call if said method can effect any user's data. In deployment, the users will be hard pressed to find the names of methods etc, but it's a good precaution. If you're incorporating Meteor's account system, I would assign permissions to users, making the default 0 and making yours one. Then, with the Meteor.call method, require a user arg, which can only really be filled with `Meteor.user()`. When parsing the data, check that the user is an admin before executing code.

Comment: That makes sense, I considered doing something like that but I thought it would be easy for a client to just manipulate their own user object and change their permission in the client, and then pass in that new object to the Meteor.call but it seems like that's not actually possible.

Comment: @Drew Every method function has access to `this.userId` which gives you the `_id` field of the currently logged in user. See http://docs.meteor.com/#method_userId

Comment: Beautiful! I was passing in the user._id on every method call and thought that it would be possible to 'spoof' that but this way seems much more efficient.